# When on Screen keyboard is visible on windows phone and user clicks on hardware back button keyboard slides down but screen moves up

Tags: windows-phone-7, sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on hybrid app.
On the windows phone, when on Screen keyboard is visible and user clicks the hardware back button, the page moves up and the header of the app goes below the screen where battery, signal strength, and time are shown. (Please see attachment).
I am not getting any event when Hardware back Button is Pressed when keyboard slides down.

This scenario is also reproducible when we used container in native app.
Its Working fine on all other platform except for windows phone.
Please suggest how to fix this issue in Hybrid app ?

Please see image attached for further understanding.
[image: Please see image attached for further understanding]

Comment: What version of Touch are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

**MainPage.xaml**

```
systemtray.isvisible = "False"
```